# How to get database object out of function

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have a function that connects to a database. After I call the function, I want it to return the database/connection object so that I am able to then use that object and perform queries on the database. How can I return the object below `$mysqli` from the function `test()` so that I can use `$mysqli` outside the function, and even in different scripts. Or should I write a specific function for each query?

```
function test($user, $pass, $db, $host){
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    else {
        echo 'Checkpoint 1 <br>';
        return $mysqli;
    }
}

test($user, $pass, $db, $host);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `vive_user` WHERE `username` LIKE"."'$name'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Comment: You should encapsulate the connection inside a class and put everything what touches that connection inside that class. Definitely **don't use the global variables**, please.

Answer (score 1):

What I use for writing big projects is the following:

```
Class MySQL
{
    protected $_conn;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_DB_NAME = DB_NAME;
        $this->_DB_USER = DB_USER;
        $this->_DB_PASS = DB_PASSWORD;
        $this->_DB_HOST = DB_HOST;
        $this->_conn = mysqli_connect($this->_DB_HOST, $this->_DB_USER, $this->_DB_PASS);
        if(!$this->_conn) {
           die('A problem has occured');
        }
    }

    public function connect() {
        if(!mysqli_select_db($this->_conn, $this->_DB_NAME)) {
            die("1st time failed<br>");
        }

        return $this->_conn;
    }
}

Class Database
{
    protected $_conn;

    public function __construct() {
        $db = new MySQL;
        $this->_conn = $db->connect();
    }

    public function retrieve() {
        $result = $this->_conn->query("SELECT * FROM mytable");
        return $result;
    }
}

$database = new Database();
$result = $database->retrieve();
```

Comment: You can also use $result = $function->_conn->query("SELECT * FROM mytable");

Comment: You could call it like that if the `$_conn` property wouldn't be protected. But anyway, why to call it like that and lose the encapsulation? It would lose the point of having 2 inherited classes completely.

Comment: i am not overly familiar with classes.. new to php, is there another way to do this? I am referencing a book that I have and it seems to use the way that I am describing. I am going to do some class research.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use **global** variable

```
$mysqli = null;

function test($user, $pass, $db, $host){
    // Here you define variable in function to global
    global $mysqli;

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    else{
        echo 'Checkpoint 1 <br>';
        return $mysqli;
    }
}

test($user, $pass, $db, $host);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `vive_user` WHERE `username` LIKE"."'$name'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Comment: Definitely **don't do this**! It's very bad design and it'll make you more problems than it solves. Google why it's not a good idea to use the global variables, or read for example [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil).

Comment: I think he don't looking for hight level difficult programing pattern. His code  looks like he is looking for easy way to do simple code. ... Your solution isn't answer for his question, it's just different, more difficult, solution and maybe he can't use it.